# how to resolve this compile error referencing code in a 3rd party asset?

Tags: unity, c#

I am having a problem importing code from a 3rd party asset into my project--this is an asset I purchased off the Unity asset store.  I did contact the vendor but haven't heard back.

The error I am getting is:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SickscoreGames' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

and my code is this simple:

```
using UnityEngine;
using SickscoreGames.HUDNavigationSystem;

namespace TatmanGames.PitcairnIsland.GamePlay
{
    public class HudController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        
    }
}
```

SickscoreGames does not have an asmdef file in their asset.   My understanding (and my researching proves) their code gets included into an assembly called Assembly-CSharp.dll so I do not need to change anything in my asmdef file.  Here it is just in case:

```
{
    "name": "TatmanGames.Pitcairn-Island",
    "rootNamespace": "TatmanGames.PitcairnIsland",
    "references": [
        "Unity.InputSystem",
        "UnityEngine.UI",
        "UnityEditor.UI",
        "Unity.TextMeshPro",
        "Cinemachine",
        "TatmanGames.Common",
        "TatmanGames.DebugUI",
        "TatmanGames.ScreenUI"
    ],
    "includePlatforms": [
        "Editor",
        "LinuxStandalone64",
        "macOSStandalone",
        "WSA",
        "WindowsStandalone64"
    ],
    "excludePlatforms": [],
    "allowUnsafeCode": false,
    "overrideReferences": false,
    "precompiledReferences": [],
    "autoReferenced": true,
    "defineConstraints": [],
    "versionDefines": [],
    "noEngineReferences": false
}
```

The structure of my project and the 3rd Asset is like this:

```
Assets
└── Pitcairn-Island
    └── Code
        ├── TatmanGames.Pitcairn-Island.asmdef
        ├── HudController.cs
        └── OtherScripts.cs

└── SickScore Games
    └── HUD-Navigation-System
        └── Scripts
            └── [their directories, scripts, no asmdef file]
```

And their code looks like this:

```
namespace SickscoreGames.HUDNavigationSystem
{
    public class AclassOfTheirs
    {
    }
}
```

Things I have tried:

1. I added Assembly-CSharp to my asmdef file
2. I have verified the namespace is correct and classes are public.
3. Reimported their asset, multiple times
4. Clean builds, many times
5. I have add their code to code execution order.
6. I started down the path of creating an asmdef for the 3rd party asset but that cascaded into changing adding additional using statements in their code, which means I cannot update the asset from the store without losing the changes.
7. I've followed suggestions on several different blogs, forums etc and I can reference those here if it helps.

Any ideas what I should be doing (or not doing)?

Thnx

Comment: Are you sure you are typing it with the proper capital letters?

Comment: Yeah I think so.  I copy/pasted the namespaces from the code.